# Cloud Code to convert column with date strings to column of dates

Tags: parse-platform

I have a column in a table in my Parse app that was mistakenly defined as string when it was supposed to be a date.  Unfortunately it has already been populated with many rows.  The format of the string data is, as an example:

11 05 18 14 04 PDT

(I believe that would be: yy MM dd hh mm z)

I'd like to run a Cloud Code job that reads the string data from each row and stores the actual date in another column (assume this new column exists). After the conversion is complete I'd manually delete the original, erroneous string column.

Below is what I currently have, now working except the imported timezone is lost in the conversion (goes from PDT to GMT).moment.js

```
Parse.Cloud.job("publicationDateMigration", function(request, status) {
  // Set up to modify user data
  var moment = require('moment');
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var counter = 0;
  // Query for all episodes
  var PSEpisode = Parse.Object.extend("PSEpisode");
  var query = new Parse.Query(PSEpisode);
  query.doesNotExist("publicationDate")
  query.limit(10);

  query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        console.log("preparing for loop-");

        var i=0;
        while (results[i]){
    var convertedPubDate = moment(results[i].get('pubDate'), "YY MM DD HH mm ss Z").toDate();

    console.log(“unconverted date is " + results[i].get('pubDate'));
    console.log("converted date is " + convertedPubDate);

        results[i].set('publicationDate', convertedPubDate);
            i++;
        }

        Parse.Object.saveAll(results);
        status.success("Date migration completed successfully.");
      },
      error: function(error) {
       status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong with date conversion.");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Moment Docs on String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) the "Z" or "ZZ" placeholder is for: Timezone offset as `+07:00` or `+0700`.

It has no understanding of "PDT", so you'll need to do a replace first to convert that to an actual offset.

```
var rawPubDate = results[i].get('pubDate');
var fixedPubDate = rawPubDate.replace('PDT', '-07:00');
fixedPubDate = fixedPubDate.replace('PST', '-08:00');
// add any others you need

var convertedPubDate = moment(fixedPubDate, 'YY MM DD HH mm ss Z').toDate();

console.log('pubDate: ' + rawPubDate 
    + ' -> ' + fixedPubDate 
    + ' -> ' + convertedPubDate);

// ... etc ...
```